# Tomcat Access Log understanding like Logs like failed Access or attemps logs from User

Tags: logs, tomcat

I installed Apache Tomcat on my Ubuntu server. The next step is, I want to interpret the access logs. However I didn't really understand the logs. Like POST / GETS, what do they mean? I really want to know how I can see the failed access attempts in the logs on my Apache Tomcat server.

A guide for beginners would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET and POST are different types of HTTP requests, you can find explanation on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get).

You will find more information about failed access attempts with error code like 403 (Forbidden), 404 (not found) by example, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Some [officiel documentation on Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html) can help you for this.